# Maintaining compability with multiple plugin version in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Assuming that extending a class from an Eclipse plugin:

```
public abstract PluginClass {

     /** @since 1.0 */
     public void doSomething() { };

     /** @since 1.1 */
     public void doSomethingElse() { };
}
```

Is it safe to override `doSomethingElse` if I still want to support the 1.0 version of the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `doSomethingElse()` is never called by any of the since 1.0 methods... that may be ok.

But a good way to manage those kind of evolutions is to have a strict bundle version numbers policy.
For that, I would recommend the "[PDE/API Tools/User Guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDE/API_Tools/User_Guide)"

> API tooling provides a builder that reports API usage and binary compatibility errors in the workspace.
>   You must configure bundles/projects that you want API tooling to report errors on and you must define an API baseline to compare against workspace projects (to report compatibility errors, missing @since tags, incorrect version numbers, etc.).
>
> An API baseline defines the state you want to compare your development workspace bundles against for the purposes of binary compatibility, bundle version numbers, and @since tags.

So in your case, if you are developing bundles for your plugin1.1, you will use your plugin 1.0 as your baseline.

Comment: Note: see also this nice recent article on API tooling: http://eclipsepde.wordpress.com/2009/06/23/configuring-api-tooling-for-existing-projects/